# How can we keep the global variable at Apex Batch

Tags: apex, batch

I have a use case to run sequence of Batch to execute my logic. There I need to have a way to start the Batch and terminate it, So for that I keep a global variable to store the records and according to the record I was start the Batch in sequence. I will share my code below and if you have any idea please share with me to overcome this issue,

I am thinking that when we start the sequence batch their might be the global variable reset.

```
global class Main_BATCH implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    global String query;
    public static List<Object_Rule__mdt> ObjectAndFieldsRule;

    global Main_BATCH() {

        ObjectAndFieldsRule = new List<Object_Rule__mdt>();

        if (ObjectAndFieldsRule.size() == 0) {
            ObjectAndFieldsRule = [
                    SELECT soco__Action__c, soco__Order__c, soco__SObject__c, 
(SELECT soco__Action__c, soco__Field_Name__c, Object_Rule__c FROM 
Field_Rules__r)
                FROM Object_Rule__mdt
                ORDER BY soco__Order__c
        ];
    }

    this.query = 'Construct query according to the meta data Master and Child records'
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> sobjects){
    try {
            batchJobId = BC.getJobId();
            'Do the logic'
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        Main_BATCH anonimizationMainBATCH = new Main_BATCH();
        ObjectAndFieldsRule.remove(0);
        if (ObjectAndFieldsRule.size() > 0) {
            Database.executeBatch(anonimizationMainBATCH, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above Batch it act as an infinite Batch with the first meta data record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables are not stored in an object's state, and therefore won't be retained across transactions in your batch. You will need to make the variable an instance variable:

```
public List<Object_Rule__mdt> ObjectAndFieldsRule;
```

---

In addition, you need to use the *same* instance of your batch when chaining:

```
Database.executeBatch(this, 200);
```

This will "keep your place" with the state you had previously.

Comment: I have tried that as well but no luck.

Comment: @Hariprasath I just realized you were creating a new copy. See edit.

Comment: yes it will terminate the infinite loop. But for the second Batch we need to again call the constructor to construct the query according to the 2nd metadata record. if we use the same batch does it call the constructor again with the previous context?

Comment: @Hariprasath Why do you need to call the constructor again? You're not done processing the first list yet. You call .remove(0), then you're calling it again, which presumably means you wish to continue processing the list of records you queried in the constructor.

Comment: In the constructor I was querying the metadata records for Example {test, 1, Contact, 
{test1, Name, Object_Rule__1}, {test2, FirstName, Object_Rule__2} , So according to the above record I need to construct the query as SELECT Name, FirstName from Contact and need to pass to the queryLocator and run the first Batch. In case if I have 2 metaData record then I need to construct the query for the 2nd record and need to do exact process as mentioned for the 1st record. So for that I need to again call the constructor.

Comment: @Hariprasath You would construct the query in the start method, not the constructor.

Comment: which means we don't need the constructor at all?

Comment: @Hariprasath You're initialize the metadata list in the constructor... you'd keep that there, presumably, otherwise you'll end up in perpetual endless loop.

Comment: sfdcfox I moved the logic to start method and called the same Batch solved the issue.